# How to make a vertical border in tailwind centered between two divs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Hello I'm trying to make a timeline and to do so I want to make a line intersecting each year like so [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8XTm.png). I am using tailwind and nextjs.

This is the code that I have so far but it's still not centering the line.

```
<div className="relative flex-col items-center justify-center">
  <span className="text-gray-400">2022</span>
  <div className=" h-20 border-l border-gray-400" />
  <span className="text-gray-400">2021</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You just forgot to add `flex` class to a parent, that's it. See [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/KSHkhGp8OL). Also just in case I would specify central div width like `w-px` (1px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is my solution using Pseudo-classes `::after`**

I have wrapped each span within a `div` tag and created an after content.

```
<div className="relative flex-col items-center justify-center">
  <div className="after:block after:bg-black after:w-[1px] after:h-10 after:mx-auto after:my-2">
    <span className="text-gray-400">2022</span>
  </div>
  <div className="after:block after:bg-black after:w-[1px] after:h-20 after:mx-auto after:my-2">
    <span className="text-gray-400">2021</span>
  </div>
  <span className="text-gray-400">2020</span>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]